# Why does the expression !(cin>>word) cause infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, if-statement, recursion, cin

I wrote a recursive function that reverses the order of words, but the function does not give an output when it takes a sentence as input. The following is my code:

```cpp
void reverseWord(void){
    string word;
    if(!(cin>>word)){
        return;
    }
    reverseWord();
    cout<<word<<" ";
    
}
```

But in the "C++ Primer(fifth edition)", there is such a sample code for reading an unknown number of strings:

```cpp
int main(){
    string word;
    while(cin>>word)
        cout<<word<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

What does the expression “!(cin<<word)” return?
And how to modify the if-statememt?

Comment: _“!(cin<<word)” is always false_ -  I'm surprised that even compiles. Did you mean `!(cin>>word)`?

Comment: Works for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/svecEeGhM How do you know the `if` is always false?

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger to see what really happens?

Comment: Also why did you remove the includes, `int main()`, etc? This just creates more work for anybody who wants to run your code.

Comment: Is your program freezing, waiting for the next input from `std::cin`? This will happen, unless you have a way of triggering eof, or some other failure on the stream.

Comment: Yes, `!(cin>>word)` will always be false because there is always more to read. To make this work you need to have a way of triggering an 'end of file' on standard input. It's possible but how it's done is platform dependent.

Comment: On Windows, try entering `Ctrl+Z` (followed by `Enter`), after entering a sentence, and pressing `Enter` after the sentence. On Unix-like systems, `Ctrl+D` will sometimes work.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. But why does the first code not stop reading after reading the carriage return character?

Comment: Because carriage return is just a `'\n` character. It can be read successfully, just the same as any other character, _without triggering eof or failure of the stream._

Comment: It doesn't, of course. *Your code* causes infinite recursion. Don't use recursion for iteration. Use iteration for iteration.

Comment: once `cin` is in error state `return` branch will never be reached.

Comment: Your function will recurse until an error (e.g. end of file) occurs on `std::cin`.   That is only infinite if an error on the stream never occurs.   Each `cin >> word` will, however, wait for input, rather than returning immediately if there is no input (and is unrelated to whether your function calls itself recursively).  Your problem is (probably) that you need to trigger such an error condition on `std::cin`.    The methods to do that (e.g. to generate end of file) vary somewhat between systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the expression !(cin>>word) cause infinite recursion?

There is nothing in your code that is causing the infinite recursion! The problem is generating eof (end-of-file) on the input stream.

##### Generating eof from the keyboard, (i.e., from `std::cin`)

On Windows systems, you can press `Ctrl+Z` to generate an eof condition from the keyboard. That will cause `cin.eof()` to become true, and subsequent input will fail.

It's a little tricky, though, because `Ctrl+Z` has to be the first character of a line for this to work. So, after you enter a sentence, you will have to do three things.

1. Press `Enter` to input the sentence. That allows your program to process the sentence. Nothing will be displayed, however, until the end of step 3.
2. Press `Ctrl+Z` at the start of the next line.
3. Press `Enter` to input the the `Ctrl+Z` from step 2.

After step 3, the sentence will be displayed with its words in reverse order.

On Unix-like systems, `Ctrl+D` will sometimes do the same thing.

Note that `Ctrl+Z` and `Ctrl+D` are not "eof characters." There is no such thing. They are regular (albeit, unprintable) characters, which, under certain system-dependent circumstances, will cause `std::cin` to be placed into an end-of-file state.

##### Demonstration using `std::stringstream`

One way to demonstrate that your program is fine, is to add a `std::istream&` as an argument, and use a `stringstream`. When the stringstream runs out of characters, it will fail.

```cpp
std::string s{ "This is a test." };
std::stringstream sst{ s };
if (!(sst >> word))  // `sst` hits eof when it (successfuly) inputs "test."
{                    // The next input attempt after that will cause `sst` to fail.
    // ...
}
```

Here is the complete program.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void reverseWord(std::istream& ist) {
    std::string word;
    if (!(ist >> word)) {
        return;
    }
    reverseWord(ist);
    std::cout << word << " ";
}

int main()
{
    std::string s{ "This is a test." };
    std::stringstream sst{ s };
    reverseWord(sst);
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output

```
test. a is This
```

##### Use a while loop

A commenter pointed out that you could solve this using a while-loop, instead of recursion. That requires storing the words for later retrieval. A `std::stack` would do the job nicely.

```cpp
void reverseWord2(std::istream& ist) {
    std::stack<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    while (ist >> word) {
        words.push(word);
    }
    while (!words.empty()) {
        std::cout << words.top() << " ";
        words.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: His code uses recursion instead of a `while` loop. I consider this as 'something wrong'.

Comment: So, you prefer a while-loop, and, I suppose, a stack of words to go with it. Okay, that would do the job nicely. I'll add a remark to my answer to that effect.

Comment: The code the OP quoted from the *C++ Primer* shows how to do it iteratively. No extra variables required.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP is trying to reverse the word order. Did you catch that?

Comment: Terminology: EOF is a _condition_, that's never identifiable as a _character_.  It's a small thing, but polluting the mental model of beginners has serious knock-on effects!

Comment: Right, you are. Mods upcoming...